# Getting cf10 to work with Apache on Mavericks

Tags: macos, apache, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We've installed cf10 on a Mac with Mavericks.

All seemed to go well.  We didn't get any errors.

- Apache is running fine.  We've setup a virtual host, and it is serving html files fine.
- Coldfusion Administrator is running fine at 127.0.0.1:8050

Yes, we did select Apache when installing CF (pointing config to /public/etc/apache2/).

But when we run a .cfm page from the virtual host on Apache, it just renders the contents of the .cfm page to the browser as text (e.g.  just get's render as text).

We have read and worked through the myriad of blog posts on how to get CF10 working on Mavericks, but with no luck, and we are starting to wonder that this may not be the problem.. as neither cf10, nor apache are 'broken' as such.  It just seems that apache is not passing .cfm file to cf for processing.

Can anyone suggest something we may be missing?

Many Thanks

Comment: What Apache version do you use? Did you install the connector or can you check if the module (mod_jk?) for coldfusion is loading?

Comment: Thanks da_did, how do I check if the module (mod_jk?) is loading?  Yes, I think we installed the connector(?).  I assume this is the step where we specified Apache when installing and had to enter the config path?  or is installing the connector done elsewhere? I'll need to get back to you on the Apache version (it's on a colleagues machine).  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried what is outlined here - http://www.n42designs.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/10/23/Running-ColdFusion-10-on-OS-X-Mavericks#.UpSklPleaSo

Comment: Thanks Scott, yes, we tried this one (and every other blog post on the topic we could fine)..  we are now at a point that CF isn't working at all .. even afer a re-install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the connector is broken currently. I recently moved to mac so I encountered the same issue. This article provides a working solution. It looks like a lot but it doesn't take long if you take time to read through it.

http://www.cfdad.com/2013/10/27/how-to-compile-adobe-coldfusion-10-apache-connector-for-osx-mavericks-10-9/

EDIT: Sorry I should provide the source for the bug: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3653076

Comment: Thanks user2591012, we tried this one as well (and every other blog post on the topic we could fine)..  we are now at a point that CF isn't working at all .. even after a complete re-install of cf.

Comment: We are going to give this one a go again.  (finally have cf working again).  Can anyone suggest if we should run all updates on CF before going through this process?  Thanks

Comment: OK.. this one worked... Thank you!  CF10 now running with Apache.  Unfortunately however, it looks like the update to brew that this approach suggested, has broken mySQL :(  The 'Mavericks' saga continues..

Answer (score 0):

It might be a simple as running the web server connection utility. [That's all I had to do with OSX 10.8.](http://iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/27/Installing-ColdFusion-10-on-OSX-108-Mountain-Lion) Brian blogged that this was all he had to do.

http://brianflove.com/2013/10/23/os-x-mavericks-and-apache/

You just have to tell it where the /conf/ folder is now located. We both used  `/private/etc/apache2/`, not `/public/`.

Comment: Thanks iKnowKungFoo, we tried this one as well..  now at a point that CF isn't working at all .. even after a complete re-install of cf.